# Selecting Which Cells Can Be Active Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a simple code to place the active cell address into another cell.

```
`Sheets("ESM").Range("K16").Value = ActiveCell.Address`
```

I would like to limit the cells that work with this code (e.g N5:AR7) but can't quite work it out.
I assume I need to somehow define the range using something like "Dim MyRange" or similar.

Would someone mind assisting?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into a condition:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("N5:AR7")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("ESM").Range("K16").Value = ActiveCell.Address
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Intersect()` method will return a Range Object that represents the intersection of two, or more, ranges.

To explain this, simply copy and paste the macro below into any standard Module. Then, ensure the active cell is within `N5:AR7`, and run the code. It will return the address of the active cell.

```
Sub TryMe()
    MsgBox Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("N5:AR7")).Address
End Sub
```

If the active cell is not within `N5:AR7` a Run Time **Error** occurs.

The **Nothing** keyword is mostly used to clear an **Object variable** back to its default of Nothing.

we can use code like shown below to **prevent the Run Time error** we get when/if the active cell does not Intersect `N5:AR7`:

```
Sub TryMeAgain()
   If Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("N5:AR7")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The active cell does NOT Intersect A1:A10"
   Else
        MsgBox "The active cell does Intersect A1:A10"
   End If  
End Sub
```